# Use Session or Cookie for Login

Tags: php, session, cookies

What method is best used when creating a login script. Should cookies or sessions be used for authentication? Cheers

Answer (score 7):

First of all, not that, in PHP, sessions generally rely on cookies to pass the session identifier from page to page.

Still, in any case :

- With cookies, everything is stored on the client's side, and goes on the network for each page -- and can be :

  - modified by the user
  - sniffed by anyone, if not using HTTPS
- With sessions, everything *(except the session identifier, of course)* is stored on the server -- which means it can only be modified by your code, and not by the user, who doesn't even see what's there.
- Cookies have a small maximum size

So, generally speaking, using sessions is often quite a good idea, when it comes to storing some kind of user-data.

Note, though, that sessions don't have a long lifetime : if the user doesn't navigate on your website for more than a couple of minutes *(half an hour, maybe ; depends on your server's coonfiguration)*, his sessions will expire.

Answer (score 1):

I would say sessions. Cookies rely on the user having cookies enabled, and personally I find sessions easier to work with.